# How to get rid of space before the first glyph in a SVG <text> element?

Tags: svg, text

[image: inkscape screenshot demonstrating the issue]

As you can see, the `<text>` element has the `x`attribute set to `0mm`, yet there is a gap between the first glyph (`H`) and the edge of the document.

I don't know what this is caused by, but if I select just the first glyph:

[image: only first H selected]

The box does extend to `x=0`, as well as slightly beyond it - which makes me think that this is a limitation of (SVG's model of) variable-width text layout perhaps?

In either case, Inkscape does show the discrepancy in the positioning - it shows the text's X coordinate at `0.635mm`:
[image: inkscape showing the X coordinate]

Which, on the other hand, makes me think that it is possible to determine *somehow*.

Of course, if all that was needed was just to align the text, I could enter `0` in the dialog, but I am generating the SVG programatically, so I either need a way to say "align the first glyph at the very edge of the `<text>` box" or to calculate the gap (so it can be put in the `dx` attribute).

A minimal test-case which illustrates this is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="150mm" version="1.1" width="150mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs/>
    <text x="0mm" y="75mm">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Font tables have a "start of line" spacing that can vary by font. See if changing the font makes a difference. (Also please post a minimum test case so we can see if you have something screwy in your CSS)

Comment: It does make a difference insofar as the size of the gap changes, but it is still present. It also changes depending on the character used. I have updated the post with a minimal example.

Comment: Yeah, so that spacing is from the font table. If you add text-decoration: underline, you'll see that the underline goes to the edge. There's no way to fix this other than measuring the space per letter either manually or by inspecting the font table, and creating an adjustment lookup table.